# How to optimize size of shared library?

Tags: c++, optimization, android-ndk, shared-libraries

Say we have huge static libraries with lots of unneeded features (in the example below we have libraries `lib1.a` and `lib2.a` with unneeded functions `g1()` and `f2()`).

We want to build shared library with a few exported methods which use only a few functions/classes from that huge libraries. See example below: we want to export function `foo()`.

**QUESTIONS**

1. Can we tell linker (`ld`) which functions/methods we want to export (like we do it for DLL in Windows)?
2. Can linker resolve dependecies and remove unneeded functions/methods? Or is there any other way to solve the problem?
3. If you have a solution, please, write the fixes for the example below.

**EXAMPLE**

File `1.h`:

```
int f1( int n );
int g1( int n );
```

File `2.h`:

```
int f2( int n );
```

File `foo.cpp`:

```
#include "1.h"
#include "2.h"

int foo( int n )
{
    return f1( n );
}
```

File `1.cpp`:

```
int f1( int n ) { return n; }
int g1( int n ) { return n; }
```

File `2.cpp`:

```
int f2( int n ) { return n; }
```

File `makefile`:

```
CXXFLAGS = -g -I. -Wall -Wno-sign-compare

all: prepare libFoo.so

clean:
    rm -f obj/*.a obj/*.o res/*.so

prepare:
    mkdir -p src
    mkdir -p obj
    mkdir -p res

lib1.a lib2.a: lib%.a: %.o
    ar r obj/$@ obj/$*.o

1.o 2.o foo.o: %.o:
    g++ $(CXXFLAGS) -c -o obj/$@ src/$*.cpp

libFoo.so: lib1.a lib2.a foo.o
    ld -shared -o res/libFoo.so obj/foo.o -Lobj -l1 -l2
```

And after making target `all` we have `nm res/libFoo.so`:

```
...
000001d8 T _Z2f1i
0000020e T _Z2g1i
000001c4 T _Z3fooi
...
```

So `ld` has removed `2.o` object file according to dependencies between object files. But didn't remove function `g1()` from `1.o`.

Comment: Because we have the resulting `.so` library ~8Mb. And some other data. Some Android devices don't have enough memory to install the app.

Comment: OK, 'android'. The magic word in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, as Basile pointed out, you should add `-fPIC` flag when building `lib{1,2}.a`.

Second, you get all of `1.o` linked in because that's [how UNIX linkers work](http://webpages.charter.net/ppluzhnikov/linker.html).

The simplest solution (much simpler than using `-flto`) is to turn on linker garbage collection by adding `-Wl,--gc-sections` to `libFoo.so` link line, and to build `lib{1,2}.a` with `-ffunction-sections -fdata-sections`. This will effectively turn each function into its own  separate "book".

Comment: I have tried `g++ $(CXXFLAGS) -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -c -o obj/$@ src/$*.cpp`. But `g1()` still exists in `libFoo.so`. Did I miss something?

Comment: Thanks for "how UNIX linkers work" link. I was looking for some article like that.

Comment: Yes: you must also turn on linker garbage collection (I updated the answer).

Comment: Thank you. It works! `:)`. Will go reading about `-ffunction-sections -fdata-sections` arguments.

Comment: As it is written in the GCC documentation it makes the resulting executable (in docs they say about executable; but the same should be applied to shared libs) larger (it makes larger the code sections that were not removed) and slower. So, we should use `-flto` if it really works and think about using `-ffunction-sections -fdata-sections` - if doesn't. Am going to build GCC 4.6

Comment: Read carefully the documentation before building GCC (in particular, the build tree should not be the source tree). And don't forget the prerequisites (like PPL).

Comment: @artyom.stv You mis-understood the GCC documentation. The options make GCC produce larger object files, but will not significantly affect the final executable (or shared library). The options also make the final link slower, but will not affect the execution speed of the executable (or the shared library) itself. The `-flto` may well give you additional speedups, so you should probably investigate it anyways.

Comment: Thank you, @Basile and @Employed Russian! You've helped me very much! I will use `-ffunction-sections -fdata-sections` (just for fun: android ndk makefiles add `-ffunction-sections` by default). And will experiment with `-flto` (I have found Android NDK with prebuilt GCC 4.6.2 - it simplifies my life `:)`).

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps **Link Time Optimization** (i.e. [`-flto`](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html) option to GCC 4.6) could help?

And also the [function attribute](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Attributes.html) `__attribute__ ((visibility ("hidden")))` and/or `__attribute__ ((weak))`

And code going into `*.so` shared objects should be compiled with `-fPIC`

Comment: I believe that not using `-fPIC` in `*.so` make them contain a big lot  of relocation instructions processed by `ld.so`

Comment: Thanks for the `-flto` hint. I think it should work. The small problem is that I am using cross-compiler under windows and it doen't know `-flto` option. Will try on Mac right now `:)`.

Comment: `-flto`  works only on recent GCC compilers (i.e. GCC **4.6**)

Comment: All GCC distributions I have found on my PCs are 4.4.* and older. Will build 4.6.2 version and try again.

Answer (score 3):

I believe that not using `-fPIC` in `*.so` make them contain a big lot  of relocation instructions processed by `ld.so`, so this is the first thing to try. `-flto` should be used both when compiling and when linking, and increase the compilation time. Adding the attributes should be done function by function, and would take a lot of your developer's time (because you need to choose which functions need them). If the code is really big (e.g. more than 100KLOC of source code), you could consider coding a GCC plugin or preferably a [GCC MELT](http://gcc-melt.org/) extension to customize your GCC 4.6 compiler to automate such tasks, but this require some work (weeks, not hours).

I am the main author of GCC MELT (and I even speak some bad Russian if it helps you), so I would be delighted to help you using MELT. But in your case, it is worthwhile only if your library is big enough to justify working more than a week on customizing GCC with MELT.